# BES upgrade from 4.1.7 to 5

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, blackberry, bes

Currently running BES 4.1.7 but for some reason bio direction calendar isnt working (BB to outlook) I dont know anything about BES and ive tried all the forum posts to fix it but nothing. So the client now wants to upgrade to 5 and see if that helps ...

Iv looked at the BES documentation and forum posts and see mixed results, does anyone know if its a simple install from 4.1.7 to 5 and whether or not i can be done?

current system is windows 2003 with exchange 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've upgraded from 3.x to 5.x and it went just great. I also moved to a new server in the process. It wasn't easy but not super hard. It involved an inplace upgrade to 5.x, then migrating to new box.

One thing I'd throw out is that for us, it was cheaper to purchase maintenance as opposed to a one-time upgrade. We learned that after purchasing the upgrade.

Since I'm not a heavy BES admin, I made sure I had a good image/backup of my production BES box before the upgrade.

Comment: Cool thanks, stupid question do i have to buy a 5 installer or can i get it from their site somewhere for free i.e. is this a free upgrade? Will be making sure i take an image before trying it. Also will i need to touch the phones, currently there are 5, im wondering if they would be better with express?

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded a client from 4.x.x to 5, as we had some calendar/contact issues as well. Upgrade didn't go smoothly, but since they had under 10 phones we just reverted a clean install and activated all the phones wirelessly since they were on a BES plan. Went off without a hitch. Given the small size of the deployment and cost issues, we went with Express.

Only word of warning is that 5 is a pig when it comes to memory use and have a look at your logging options - it can easily spiral out of control and soak up GBs of HDD space.

I'd also offer up this - the user that started this later had more sync issues while the rest of the users had none. What fixed the latter issues was a hidden menu in  Options > Advanced Options > Enterprise Activation and in the email field press and hold the ALT key and type CNFG. Once you enter this, a menu will appear and you can toggle "Wireless Sync" to no. Exit and wait a minute then repeat the process setting sync to yes. The unit then appears to do a resync of all its data, which fixed my issues.